# Apple Books app in IOS 13 does not correctly play mp3

Tags: books

I can't figure out why I am the only one having so many problem with the Apple Books app and no one else is complaining about them on the internet.  I just want to focus on one of those problem but to give you an idea of how many problems resulted ever since they divided iTunes into three apps, 1) music 2) podcasts 3) books, let me list them:

1. Cannot play mp3s in a series (it stops after playing one mp3)
2. Cannot add mp3s to a collection of books
3. After Books plays half of the mp3, you cannot fast forward or rewind

Let's focus on 3 first since that is the toughest to work around.  Now, admittedly there is a work around, just convert mp3 to mp4, but I would rather not do that since mp4s are twice as long and, two, since the mp3s are an hour long (they are books after all) it takes roughly 20 to 30 minutes to convert the mp3 to mp4.

Let me describe the problem in more detail.  Suppose you have an mp3 which is an hour long.  Books thinks it is only half that time, so after minute 30, the mp3 will permanently show the time as 0, so you can't forward or rewind for the second half of the mp3.

Again, the best solution would be to simply go back to the app that had all apps combined into one, because ever since then, listening to Books requires way too much effort.